# Is it possible to suppress values for measure columns in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

It is known that there is an option to suppress or repeat data by setting in Column Properties window.

However, we noticed that it works only for dimension columns, but when we have an analysis from two or three fact tables and common dimensions with appropriate levels, dimension values are being suppressed, but measure column values are being repeated even though values are the same and 'suppress' option is enabled.

Is there any way to suppress them too?
I understand that if you have 1 record in one fact table, 2 in another and 3 in the third table and when you join them with inner and outer joins, you will always have columns repeated, but in BI can we make it more user friendly by suppressing equal values?

[image]

In the image above, all columns till red square starts are dimension columns and they are suppressed, but columns inside square are measure columns and even though suppress option is enabled they are repeated for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't because it doesn't make sense. Measures aggregate depending on the grain of the query and the result set.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Chris! I was thinking the same, but wondering maybe I am missing something